# How to detect whether a variable is a specific or not?

Tags: python, class

I used a graph package coinor.gimpy to implement some algorithms in network theory. And I want to use the graph class as one input of a function, however, I want to check whether this variable is this class or not, I don't know how to do, following are some of the code.

```
from coinor.gimpy import Graph    
g=Graph()
print type(g)
```

and the result is

```
<class 'coinor.gimpy.graph.Graph'>
```

Then inside one function, the code might be like the following,

```
def Dijkstra(g)
    if type(g) == ??
        then ...
```

my question is: what should I write to replace the question mark? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most common method is to use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
isinstance(g, Graph)
```

This will return `True` or `False` depending on whether or not `g` is an instance or subclass of `Graph`.

---

An alternate approach is to use `type` and the [`is`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#is) operator:

```
type(g) is Graph
```

This will return `True` or `False` depending on whether or not `g` is of type `Graph`.